# Removing div tag from url loaded from webview android

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I  am loading a url into webview using web.loadUrl(url);. Now i want to remove part the body content when the url finished loading.

Data from the url is as follows :

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="header" data-role="header" data-theme="a"> 
 <a data-icon="back" class="header-icon" data-iconpos="notext" href="mymob-web-mobile/restricted/menu.xhtml" data-ajax="false"> <span>Back</span> </a> 
  <!--Title--> 
 <h1>???help.main.title???</h1> 
 </div> 

<div id="well">Hello World</div>
<body>
</html>
```

I want to remove this part in the url

```
<div class="header" data-role="header" data-theme="a"> 
 <a data-icon="back" class="header-icon" data-iconpos="notext" href="mymob-web-mobile/restricted/menu.xhtml" data-ajax="false"> <span>Back</span> </a> 
  <!--Title--> 
 <h1>???help.main.title???</h1> 
 </div>
```

After some researh i come to this solution:

```
web= (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);

        web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
            {
                web.loadUrl("javascript:var con = document.getElementByTagName('<div class=\"header\" data-role=\"header\" data-theme=\"a\"> '); " +
                        "con.style.display = 'none'; ");
            }
        });


        web.clearCache(true);
        web.clearHistory();
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

        web.loadUrl(Constant.URL_AIDE, headers);
```

But the div element is not being removed.

a summery is , div to remove

```
<div class="header" data-role="header" data-theme="a"> 
 <a data-icon="back" class="header-icon" data-iconpos="notext" href="mymob-web-mobile/restricted/menu.xhtml" data-ajax="false"> <span>Back</span> </a> 
  <!--Title--> 
 <h1>???help.main.title???</h1> 
 </div>
```

expected result

```
<html>
<body>


<div id="well">Hello World</div>
<body>
</html>
```

any idea please

Comment: create css file and put inside assets folder and load url by applying css file path

Comment: @BirajZalavadia how can you achieve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use getElementsByClassName() to access the div. Here is my solution please try it.

```
web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){

            web.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('header')[0].style.display=\"none\";");

        }
    })
```

Comment: Where should I define url of the webpage in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript is incorrect. There is no such thing as `getElementByTagName`, other than `getElementById` other `getElements...` functions return a list of nodes. It should be something like:

```
[].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("header")).forEach(function(element) {element.style.display = 'none';});
```